# Custom search indexing algorithm for "... WHERE word like 'ab%' order by relevace"

Tags: algorithm, search, indexing

I have an array of string and int pairs. I would like to search for strings and list them in the order of their corresponding int value.

```
class WordClass
{
 public string Word;
 public int Relevance;
}
WordClass words[];
```

I would like to implement an indexing algorithm for this, but do not know what algorithm to use.

In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word like 'ab%' order by relevance
```

I have created an AVL tree, but I realized that one AVL tree is not really suitable for this purpose.

The algorithm should be very quick.

Thank you

Comment: Define *relevance*. Should it be according to the levenstein distance?

Comment: "In SQL it would be something like this" - No it isn't... why `%`? where are the multiple words? Or I misunderstood the requirements..

Comment: do you want to retrieve words or occurrences of words. If it's only words themselves as your query suggests, how is relevance supposed to be determined?

Comment: Each string has its corresponding int value. These int values are increased by some background logic. For example I would like to search for the WORD that starts with 'ab' and its corresponding 'relevance' int value is the highest among the words that also starts with 'ab'. So, {Abba, 20}, {Abigail, 50} should return Abigail, because its int value is higher.

Answer (score 0):

A Trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a good data-structure if you want to find all the words that start with a prefix. You can get all the words and then sort them by relevance.

However this won't be very efficient if you only want to only select the top-k highest relevant words.

Comment: Trie sounds promising, but I think to find the most relevant word is very expensive, because you have to iterate all the items. Let's say if I'm searching for all the words that start with letter 'a' and there are 1000 or 10000 words that starts with 'a' I have to read all of them.